# How to reset window duration after each value in throttle in Rx.js?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'd like be notified when a new value is produced, but only if some time has passed since the previous value was produced.

E.g. if a source starts producing values (at t=0s) and produces new value every second for 10 seconds, then stops for 5 seconds and then starts again (at t=15s), assuming that window duration is set to less than 5 seconds, I'd like to be notified only about values at t=0 and t=15 (immediately after they are produced). Something like throttle, but where each new value resets the window duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in a rush but you it seems to be working : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj04mvds/5/)

The idea is to start with the first value, debounce with the specified duration, and take the next value after the debounce. `source` has to be shared as it will be subscribed many times over.

```
var ta_message = document.getElementById('ta_message');
var ta_intermediary = document.getElementById('ta_intermediary');
var ta_result = document.getElementById('ta_result');

function emits ( who, who_ ) {return function ( x ) {
 who.innerHTML = [who.innerHTML, who_ + " emits " + JSON.stringify(x)].join("\n");
};}

var count = 0;
var Xms = 1700;

var source$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.getElementById('source'), 'click')
  .map(function(){return ++count;})
 .do(emits(ta_message, 'count'))
 .share();

var firstNextItem$ = source$
  .debounce(Xms)
  .flatMapLatest(function(){return source$.take(1);})
  .do(emits(ta_intermediary, 'first value after Xms pause'))
;

var result$ = Rx.Observable.merge(source$.take(1), firstNextItem$)
      .do(emits(ta_result, 'result'))
;

result$.subscribe(function(){});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the demo seems to be working more like plain throttle, i.e. if I click continuously on the "source" button I'm getting a new value in the second textarea every 1.7s (or whatever `Xms` value  I set).

Comment: Updated the solution to use `debounce` as a closer selector. Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: Almost :) Currently it works like debounce, but returns the first value instead of the last one (which is ok). When I click "source" button, I'd like to get the first value immediately, but get the next value (also immediately) only if there was a break longer than `Xms` between values. 

So it should work like: if there's a new value in the original source, immediately emit this value, if it's the first one; otherwise, check when was the previous one and if it was earlier than Xms period, immediately emit the new value.

Comment: And then end the stream right? Because this behaviour that you suggest resist recursion. Well actually just got another idea. I'll try right now. Also you should update your question to precise that you want the values immediately

Comment: The whole reason for it is that I'm detecting motion in a video stream and the detection is executed a few times per second. I'd like to have start and end times of periods when motion was detected, assuming window duration of X seconds. Getting end times is easy, because it's just debounce, but I don't know how to get start times.